# Jade Template Engine - Change section title in main pages

Tags: javascript, node.js, pug, template-engine

I use Jade Template Engine. I need to change section title in main pages.

```
h1.text-center.main-title| The title here
```

The title coming form other part to the page by this code

```
include  ./parts/_page-header.jade
```

I try to use case, block & vars it's don't work with me

I need any way to include the part in the page and change the title content in this page only.

Comment: you should pass the title into the locals object ans write `h1=locals.pageTitle`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```
-if(!pagetitle) pagetitle = ''
-var pagetitle = "Home" 
h1.text-center.main-title| #{pagetitle}
```

It'll work